# How to convert Oracle pivot function query to MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Please find the below query and as there is no Pivot function in MySQL to use. Please provide the MySQL query for the same. Please find the link after the below query for table picture and the expected data.

````
SELECT
   *
FROM
   (
       SELECT
           *
       FROM
           (
               SELECT
                   X.*,
                   Y.status,
                   Y.create_date,
                   Z.x_some_id
               FROM
                   X csv
                   LEFT JOIN Y lsh ON X.id = Y.x_id
                                                          AND Y.type = 'STATUS'
                   LEFT JOIN Z vi ON X.some_id = Z.x_some_id
               WHERE
                   X.some_col = 'abc'
           ) PIVOT (
               MAX ( create_date )
               FOR status
               IN ( 'CONFIRMED',
               'UNCONFIRMED' )
           )
   )
ORDER BY
   date ASC```

 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmNJt.png
````

Comment: I'd prefer to start over, with sample data and a desired result. Accordingly, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Table X
 id  x_name x_email x_phone
 --  ------ ------- -------
 1   xxx     yyy@a    91234
 2   yyy     xxx@a    98321
 3   zzz     zzz@a    94251
    
    Table Y
    id  status     created_date  x_id
    --  ------     ------------  ----
    1   RECONFIRM  21-10-2019    1
    2   CONFIRMED  10-10-2019    3
    3   CONFIRMED  15-10-2019    1
    
    Table Z
    id  x_id
    --  ----
    1   2
    2   3
    3   1
    id  x_name x_email x_phone confirmed reconfirmed
    --  ------ ------- ------- --------- -----------
    1   xxx    xxx@a   91234   15-10-2019 21-10-2019

Comment: i can only refer you again to my previous comment, and note that an Edit button is provided.

Comment: @Strawberry I've added the image link. pls refer to it.

Comment: No thanks. Why not actually read and respond to the accepted answer at the link provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT X.ID,  -- add the extra columns you want here
       MAX(CASE WHEN Y.status = 'CONFIRMED' THEN Y.create_date END) as confirmed,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Y.status = 'UNCONFIRMED' THEN Y.create_date END) as unconfirmed
FROM X LEFT JOIN
     Y
     ON X.id = Y.x_id AND 
        Y.type = 'STATUS' LEFT JOIN
     Z
     ON X.some_id = Z.x_some_id
WHERE X.some_col = 'abc'
GROUP BY X.id;  -- whatever columns you want to lead the
```